# msbuild - UnitTestFramework reference could not be resolved

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to run msbuild in Jenkins.
When it reaches the UniTest-Project an error occures:

```
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\***\workspace\***.sln" (1) is building "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\***\workspace\***.unitTests\***.unitTests.csproj" (4) on node 0 (default targets).
Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0", which is not supported by this version of MSBuild. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="3.5".
ResolveAssemblyReferences:
  Primary reference "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
      Could not find dependent files. Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NetFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.6\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.exe", but it didn't exist.
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(11,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(11,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(24,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(24,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(37,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(37,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
CalculatorServiceTest.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\***\workspace\***.unitTests\***.unitTests.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\***\workspace\***.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Any suggestions what the problem could be? Running ms build from the command works for the solution and without any additional parameters **when** the project was compiles in VS **bevor**. After a clean solution the same errors occur. Must be some parameter or reference problem; Line two talks bout v4 and v3.5 problems; but i can't figure out how to solve this.

Greets

Comment: I can't understand when the error occurs, when building from the IDE, or from a command line?  What is "bevor" and which command shell are you trying to build from?  Seems like you've got a 3.5 command shell trying to build with 4.0 assemblies.

Comment: `UnitTestFramework` is a part of VS Professional and higher. It is not available with VS Community e.g. This may be one more reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error info directly shows that you use incorrect version of MSBuild

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Try to rebuild with MSBuild 4.0

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe *.sln /t:rebuild
```

OR/AND from VS2010 Command Line.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem which seemed to be caused by running Jenkins as a service under the SYSTEM account. Somehow cmd.exe was not referencing all the necessary environment variables to be able to find my NUnit assemblies.

If you're running Jenkins as a service, try setting it to run as your user account and see if that helps.

Comment: You can check this by downloading PSTools (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) and running PsTools/PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe which allows you to run a command prompt as the local system user. This then allows you to mimic jenkins and run command line tools as if you were that user. (Discovered via http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/jenkins-git-clone-via-ssh-on-windows-7-x64)

Answer (score 0):

Im building from the default windows cmd using:

> C:...\MSBuild.exe ***.sln

The solution-projects are all 3.5; only the Unit-Test Project is 4.0 (as you can't change this)

I just mentioned, that building it that way works, when i build it first with VS and don't deleted (clean solution) the binaries. Never mind.

How do i have to use msbuild from cmd to build a *.sln including unittests?